# Error al intentar usar el comando ng add apollo-angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, graphql

Estoy intentando usar ng add apollo-angular para manejar los query y mutaciones en frontend pero al intentarla ejecutar aparece este error:
**"We couldn't enable 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.
It's required by '@apollo/client/core' package so please add it to your tsconfig.
Bootstrap call not found"** pero el problema es que yo ya tengo en mi archivo tsconfig.ts esta variable habilitada como lo muestro a continuacion:

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
        "ES2022",
        "dom"
    ]
},
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false
}
```

}
la version angular que utilizo es la 16.0.3 y la version de apolo-angular es la 5.0